# How to optimize my table to get faster query result?

Tags: postgresql

create table car_park {
id bigint primary key,
car_number bytea,
the_date date,
the_time timestamp
}

This table has thousands of rows daily in order to register coming/leaving cars in the car park. It will be huge table after several months. How to rebuilt or optimize my table to get fast query results?

Comment: Indexes are usually the thing to do, but I'm interested why `car_number` is bytea. What does it contain? Why do you have a date and a time stamp field when the latter contains the date already?

Comment: Use Partition and Indexes, but in the end everything depends upon what kind of query you are going to execute and how much data your query is fetching.

Comment: Please show us your query statements and the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE. Without it, there is nothing to optimise. Thousands of rows daily isn't that much, we do this per second.

Comment: car_number is a photo which is taken by security camera

Answer (score 0):

Table [Partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html) can be useful.